Как добавить программу в Windows PATH с помощью Python
У меня есть программа example.exe которую можно запускать с параметрами, например:

example 10 -a

Мне нужно добавить ее в PATH чтобы ее можно было вызывать где угодно
Как это сделать с помощью языка Python?

У меня тоже такой вопрос был

import os
c = 'wmic environment where name="PATH" set variablevalue="C:\Test;%PATH%"'
os.system(c)

Проверял на python 3.8 и windows 10. Нужны права администратора, т.к. меняет пользовательскую PATH и системную PATH.
import os
c = 'setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\\test2"'
os.system(c)

Меняет пользовательскую PATH, повышенные права не нужны.
import os
c = 'setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\\test2"'
os.system(c)

Меняет системную переменную PATH, поэтому нужны права.
